# vue/vuetify autofill password incompatible issues on native ios app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have created an ios container for a web app implemented using vue js with vuetify ui library. Below is the login screen code for username and password.

```
<v-text-field outlined v-model="email" type="email" required label="Email" autocomplete="username"
                                  background-color="white"
                                  placeholder=" " persistent-placeholder
                                  :rules="[inputRules.requiredEmail,inputRules.email]"/>
<v-text-field outlined v-model="password" type="password" required label="Password" autocomplete="current-password"
                                  background-color="white"
                                  placeholder=" " persistent-placeholder
                                  :rules="[inputRules.requiredPassword]"/>
```

There in the login screen I need to get the credentials using autofill option. When I am trying to get the both username and password together from saved passwords in the iphone, only password field was not set correctly because when I am clicked on the password field it will disappear. This issue happens only on the ios app which is behaving as the IOS container for the web view. When I am trying via safari browser on the iphone also it's working fine. So issue is existed only on native ios. Anyone knows how to get rid from this issue?